# "Site Not Available" PSN error?

Tags: technical-issues, psn

Trying to access PSN (http://store.playstation.com) from any PC gets me this error (before even prompting me to login):

[image: psn error]

Video:

[EDIT] I even get this error using the Android app:

[image: psn app error]

What I find strange is this a PSN error. Not a browser error, but something PSN is saying.

Or trying to login to PSN on PS3/PS4/phone also gets a generic error. What's wrong, what does this error indicate? How can this be fixed?

I've tried rebooting, I've tried Chrome in incognito mode, I've tried different computers etc. All get the error. This has been like this for 24+ hours for me now.

I'm in Albany NY

[EDIT] Sony support was no help. They replied;

> xxxxxxx: Unfortunately this error does not belong to us https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZjEI.png, please try another browser or another internet connection.

What's even more odd, is that I was able to update my PSTV during all this. But as soon as I tried logging onto PSN on the PSTV, I got a connection error. The internet is working fine though.

Comment: Looks like it could be down in your area. Try https://downdetector.com/status/playstation-network

Comment: I'm able to connect with my phone no problem. I'm located in Michigan.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console _(ctrl+shift+I --> console)_?

Comment: Looking at your phone screenshot, you're trying to connect via wireless? Is this the same connection as your PS4/PS3 are using? It's possible someone is serving you a fake PStore page, but I don't know why they would just give you an error message.

Comment: @originaluser Yes, same network. It's my own network in my house, so I'm uh assuming there's no man-in-middle attack trying to redirect me to a fake store

Comment: Considering it works for everyone else, it's either a problem with your network or your ISP. Considering the issue and custom 404 page, my guess is some form if DNS redirect or something is messing with the headers.

Comment: @Thebluefish I almost agree, but this even happens on my PSTV (can't connect). So strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding [one other person with the same issue on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/38gdbr/psn_has_been_down_for_me_for_2_days_now_how_can_i/), they later left a comment around midnight that "It's back" and sure enough it was fixed.

It seems Sony resolved this, even their chat support blamed my ISP.